# How to make my password unchangeable

Tags: 12.04

How do I make my password unchangeable by another administrator in my system on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin)?

I am an administrator in my machine and I don't want another administrator to reset my password. Is it possible?

Comment: not unless they don't have sudo rights...

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to make your password unchangeable.
The only way is to limit the privileges of other administrators.

Comment: This is not the case. If `/etc/passwd` is not writable (on a read-only filesystem, or after removing the SETUID bit from `/usr/bin/passwd`, or garbage in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` or passwords on a down NIS server, or ...) nobody will be able to change his password. Pathological cases, true, but I have experiened each.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are "an administrator", it means that you can run processes with UID = 0. Running with UID 0 grants a process many capabilities.

if the O.P. is "an administrator", it means that he/she can run processes with UID = 0. Running with UID 0 grants a process many capabilities.

Can you tell the difference between them? The system cannot. UID=0 and UID=0 are the same.

You are really asking "Can one use the powers of UID=0 to protect against UID=0?".

If the O.P. is malicious, you must solve the problem in the Real World.